# Using SUMPRODUCT with TRANSPOSE

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use [`TRANSPOSE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php) inside [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumproduct.php). What's wrong with my formula?

[image]

I use Excel 2013 if that matters.

Comment: Your formula is correct, you just need to press `Crtl+Shift+Enter` to confirm it and make it an array formula. In some cases `SUMPRODUCT` will sometimes automatically handle array treatment of arguments, but a `TRANSPOSE` argument apparently is not among them.

Comment: @andyholaday Thanks, this was indeed the issue. Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your formula is correct, you just need to press `Crtl+Shift+Enter` to confirm it and make it an array formula. In some cases `SUMPRODUCT` will sometimes automatically handle array treatment of arguments, but a `TRANSPOSE` argument apparently is not among them.

Comment: My question about this is: WHY does this need to be entered as an array formula (ctrl-shift-enter)? Isn't this just an XLS bug that MS need to fix?

Comment: @nickpharris I don't have an answer for you. To hazard a guess, while `SUMPRODUCT` will treat ranges as arrays as arrays, `TRANSPOSE` actually requires array entry, and that requirement bubbles up through the parsing stack.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what result you want but would be interested to know whether:

```
=MMULT(D9:F9,D3:D5)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is such.

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed I had tried with `MMULT`. I must admit I wonder when `MULT` is useful: do you know [in what situations can't I use SUMPRODUCT instead of MMULT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21896228/395857)

Comment: I think the two questions are different: this question is more about using Crtl+Shift+Enter, while the other focuses on the usefulness of `MMULT`.