# In what situations can't I use SUMPRODUCT instead of MMULT?

Tags: excel

According to the Microsoft documentation, [`MMULT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mmult-HP005209181.aspx) returns the matrix product of two arrays while [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx) multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products.

I don't see in what situations I cannot use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `MMULT`. And I missing something?

Comment: You did see the MMULT requirement that "The number of *columns* in array1 must be the same as the number of *rows* in array2", right? This is not what `SUMPRODUCT` expects. Edit: Barry gives a much better explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` only allows you to operate on same sized arrays to get a single result.

`MMULT` can multiply differently sized arrays (as long as the rules are followed) to give you an array result.

The rule is that the first argument of `MMULT` must have as many columns as the second argument has rows, so you can use this formula, for example

`=MMULT(A3:C6,E3:E5)`

where the first array is 4*3 (4 rows by 3 columns) and the second argument is 3*1 (3 rows by 1 column) and that returns a 4*1 array

Comment: Oh OK, thanks. In short, `SUMPRODUCT` computes the dot product (wouldn't have it been clearer to call it `DOTPRODUCT`?) while `MMULT` is the matrix multiplication (sometimes function names get abbreviated, sometimes not). Sorry I got confused as for whatever reason (maybe dimensionality issue?) `MMULT` only works with 2 inputs while `SUMPRODUCT` works with 2 to 30 (why 30?) inputs.

Comment: Is "dot product" for vectors? `SUMPRODUCT` can still use matrices - as long as they are the same size and shape, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D5,E2:H6)` - 30 is the limit in Excel 2003, don't know why but also applies to many other functions - in later versions the limit is 255

Comment: Good point, dot product is for vector only, a more proper term would be [element-by-element multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/times.html) or element-wise multiplication, but yeah it starts to make the function name a bit too long. Anyway so long with terms, thanks for the explanation!