# SUMPRODUCT returns #Value when cell has an empty string (="")

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use `SUMPRODUCT` function for the following scenario

```
A    B
1    ""
2    1
```

where the value `""` was entered using the formula `=""` as part of an `IF` condition like this: `IF (condition_is_true, value, "")`. I would like to visualize in my table when I have an empty value from zero value, that is why in the `IF` statement I am using `""` instead of `0`(that would produce the right result).

I am using `SUMPRODUCT` as follow:

```
SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, B1:B2)
```

expecting to return the value `2`

For excluding the `""` cells, I was expecting that the following should work:

```
SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, --(B1:B2<>""), B1:B2)
```

but in this case, it doesn't work because the cell is not blank, I was trying several options but in all cases, I am getting `#VALUE` as result in all cases.

**Note:** I found some similar question but not addressing this specific case.

**UPDATE**: I realized working on my real situation, the issue was not the blanks, but rather trying to use `SUMPRODUCT` function when one argument is on row format and the other one in column format, for some reason it doesn't work, transposing the second argument using `TRANSPOSE` function works, I don't know why. The following picture shows the situation
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `O365` and your first formula works for me for conditional blanks.

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, B1:B2)`

for test purpose, `B1` has `=IF(C1<>"",1,"")`. See below snapshot.

[image]

You can use an `IF` formula inside `SUMPRODUCT` like below to get around the issue.

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, IF(B1:B2<>"",B1:B2,0))`

**Edit:**

`SUMPRODUCT` is an array formula and it requires the arrays involved in the operation of the same dimension & size.

So in principle, when we multiply two columns the data array is (note semicolon between entries):

`{A1;A2;A3;A4;....An}`

whereas when it is spread across a row then it is (note comma between entries):

`{A1;B1;C1;D1;E1....}`

So when you try to implement it for data spread in rows with columnar data, the array size criteria is fulfilled but the dimension criteria is not and therefore it returns an error! Applying `TRANSPOSE` changes the array to matching dimension and therefore returns result on expected lines.

Comment: it works for me too, Translating my real situation to this sample I realized the issue is not the blanks, but instead the second argument was a column and the second was a row in `SUMPRODUCT` function. I transposed it using `TRANSPOSE` function and it works. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895201/using-sumproduct-with-transpose/21896308) helps me to think about using this function. I will provide an update to the question to clarify this. I don't really know what we need it.

Comment: @DavidLeal Ah, I understood now. Please see my explanation in the edit portion.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit 3rd array of your formula. Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2, --(B1:B2<>""))
```